# Kusto project only non null values or drop columns with null values

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

When I query, I get a row, with multiple null values. is there a way to either not get null values in the result, or drop the columns with null values?

sample code is:

```
let table_name = datatable(name:string, date_part:datetime, job_1:string, job_2:string, job_3:string, job_4:string)
[
     "David", datetime(2022-05-9), "Architect", "", "", "Engineer"
  
];
table_name 
|where name == "David" and (date_part  between (now() .. -10d))
|project  (job_1),(job_2),(job_3),(job_4)
```

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Enumerated columns` names e.g., col_1, col_2, etc. are often indication for bad data modeling (2) Returning result set with unstable structure is a risky idea 
(3) As the documentation states "The string data type doesn't support null values.", so I wonder what type are job_1, job_2 etc.
Please add a data sample and share some more information about your challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let table_name = datatable(name:string, date_part:datetime, job_1:string, job_2:string, job_3:string, job_4:string)
[
     "David", datetime(2022-05-9), "Architect", "", "", "Engineer"
    ,"David", datetime(2022-05-6), "Musician", "Producer", "", ""
];
table_name 
| where name == "David" and (date_part  between (now() .. -10d))
| project-keep job_*
| evaluate narrow()
| where isnotempty(Value)
| evaluate pivot(Column, any(Value), Row)
| project-away Row
```

| job_1 | job_2 | job_4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Architect |  | Engineer |
| Musician | Producer |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3VQTUvEMBC9C/6HoadE0qVbP8CVPYh6FMSDF5ElbYfdrG1S0mnLgj/epDGrZTEQJvPmvTeTqZGAZFHjRssGYQ2VJDkBzAOrjqzSW%20Fh3LTS0sq/SDUoYG%20KzfLI8Fk%20yy5n2dVPxs/PwJ33EKaTPMpBVUno4r1ZnuV5ml2nt1xAcm/LnSIsyTGSeJ/0VmlEm/z6iP99brzPc9%20pUknt5S/WVH3p5NEy2HzchfhnJQH4gnGHFiFsaR1HBqkrYMflABRII6IGps3IOCwWkC6zivPo0lqzdz9JPxHbaS0XsYKDrHtn5FpY68XzxqrThrBp6cDeHBH5ia5VgyH2YOq%200cINFokCXs14MoAc5cEXvgGpXiDzAQIAAA==)

Comment: Thank you so much David, I updated the datatable based on your example, but on my example it is only one row. Also all types are String. BTW it worked perfectly, so thank you sooo much :)